# Drop rows based on indices in a sorted df

Tags: python, pandas

How can I, after sorting the rows of a df, drop rows based on their index, and not their new row position?

A small example of what I mean:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {
        'ELEMENT_DATE' : ['01/03/2010', '01/01/2010', '01/02/2010', '01/04/2010', '01/5/2010'],
        'ELEMENT' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df['ELEMENT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ELEMENT_DATE'])
print("original order:")
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx, row['ELEMENT'])
print("***")

df = df.sort_values(by=['ELEMENT_DATE'])
print("sorted by date:")
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx, row['ELEMENT'])
print("***")

indexes_to_drop = [0,1]
df.drop(df.index[indexes_to_drop], inplace=True)
print("dropped indices 0 and 1:")
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx, row['ELEMENT'])
```

The code above prints:

```
original order:
0 A
1 B
2 C
3 D
4 E
***
sorted by date:
1 B
2 C
0 A
3 D
4 E
***
dropped indices 0 and 1:
0 A
3 D
4 E
```

But I am specifying `indexes_to_drop = [0,1]`, so in this example I would like to drop rows `0 A` and `1 B`.

In general, I want to use a list of integers for a (potentially sorted) df that has integer indices, and drop the rows corresponding  to these indices (like `0 A` and `1 B` above). The indices of the df should not be changed with `reset_index` or something else.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why don't you just drop `indexes_to_drop` instead of `df.index[indexes_to_drop]` if you want to drop the labels, not the index locations?

Comment: @user3483203 That works, can  you make this an answer?

Comment: I posted a bit more information about what you are running into @tkja.

Comment: @user3483203 That clarifies it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a slight misconception of what you should be passing to `pd.DataFrame.drop`.  [From the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), the first argument is `labels`:

> `labels` : single label or list-like Index or column labels to drop.

These are labels, not integer values, so dropping `0` will drop rows with an index label of `0` regardless if that same row is returned by `df.iloc[0]`.

When you use `indexes_to_drop` to index `df.index`, you change the labels you want to drop into the labels that are present at the indices contained in the array, in this case `[1, 2]`

```
>>> df.index[indexes_to_drop]
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

Instead, the solution is simple, just let `drop` do what it does by default, and drop the labels you have identified.

```
>>> df.drop(indexes_to_drop)
  ELEMENT_DATE ELEMENT
2   2010-01-02       C
3   2010-01-04       D
4   2010-01-05       E
```